# source code corresponding to gluon openjavafx binary releases

Tags: javafx, gluon

The Open JavaFX binary releases have moved to gluon but they don't include any source release on the download page.  Even if it was provided (and it isn't) instructions and a link to a version control system is insufficient given OpenJavaFX is GPL 2. e.g. https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.en.html#DistributeWithSourceOnInternet

Will such a release ever be provided.  And the same question goes for javadocs suitable for an ide.

Comment: The [SDK downloads](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) contain a `src.zip` with the sources, and JavaDoc is [online](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/). If you go through [Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2/), you can get each of the JavaFX artifacts with source code and javadoc.

Comment: the src.zip is only suitable for an ide, it doesn't include enough to recompile the library as required by GPL2.

there is no link to the maven artifacts on the download page, and even if there were it is insufficient for GPL2.